# @property decorator of python not working

Tags: python

I was trying to set some property to a class via decorator but its not working as expected. How can I get the age via property decorator.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.age = ""
        self.dob = ""

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self._age = value

    @property
    def dob(self):
        return self._dob

    @dob.setter
    def dob(self, value):
        self._dob = value
        self._age = 20 #Utility.getAge(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Person()
    p.name = "Andrew"
    p.dob = "10-10-1980"
    print p.name
    print p.dob
    print p.age
```

Output:

```
John
10-10-1980
#20 <-missing
```

I am not getting the age. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, the instance variables in your dunder init are overwriting your properties, they should be prefixed with underscore

Comment: tried it still no luck. it seems like self._age = Utility.getAge(value) never sets the age property.

Comment: I didn't even notice that part, what do you expect that to do? What is Utility?

Comment: It converts the dob to age. It working fine if i called it in main

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Works fine for me (after replacing `Utility.getAge(value)`) which leads to think the problem is in `Utility` so you're asking the wrong question here

Comment: Tried that as well , even if you replace "Utility.getAge" method with a fixed integer , still age property doesn't get set.

Comment: Say if set a fixed value 20. i would have gotten John
10-10-1980 ,  20

Comment: I changed to `self._age = value + " years old"` and it works fine. Prints: `Andrew
10-10-1980
10-10-1980 years old` so you should post a [mre]

Comment: ohh my lord  i tried it on python3 , it is working fine but on 2.7 it isn't ..which version u tried on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this took me a while to actually find out why the above code was not working in python 2.7.

If you look at the [`property` documentation for python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#property), you would find that the class that has the property decorators used is actually inheriting `object` class and your code doesn't.

Now, when you don't inherit, the property decorator actually doesn't work and setting or getting properties don't work either
(Put a print statements in getter or setter functions and they wont be printed since they were never invoked while setting `p.name` or getting `p.name`).

**Question : So how come get/set for p.name and p.dob works?**

Since, you are not inheriting object class in your class, the property decorators are useless, they are not being invoked but have created those property on the Person object. [image]

But, when you use below code, you are explicitly setting those value (without the use of setters), hence thy are printed and p.age never got assigned any value.

```
p.name = "Andrew"
p.dob = "10-10-1980"
```

**Code Fix :** Update your class declaration to -->

```
class Person(object):
```

and setters/getters would work (check using print statements) and `self.age` would also work.

**Bonus : Python3 onwards, all classes, by default, inherit object class.**